# CSS aligned rows without wrapper div

Tags: css

This is what I have:

[image]

and this is what I want:

[image]

I have a container div around all of the smaller divs, and the smaller divs are floated left. How can I get them to align in perfect rows like the bottom image? This would be easy but the catch is I don't want to use a container div for each row since I want the number of images per row to be fluid (container width is variable). Is this even possible without JS hacks?

Comment: Can you please post a few snippets of your HTML and CSS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just change the float:left to display:inline-block. That will lay the images out in rows, just like text layout, which sounds like what you want to do.

Comment: Yes, this works, I didn't know there was a way to get inline-block on DIVs in IE7: http://foohack.com/2007/11/cross-browser-support-for-inline-block-styling/

Answer (score 1):

I post this with some apprehension because I don't know what you qualify as a Javascript hack... There is a plug-in that would work well for this, [Masonry JS](http://masonry.desandro.com/). But if you consider a plug-in a hack then I would suggest applying a `display:inline-block;` to the elements that you want in a line and removing the `float:left;` property.